# React flick when switching between pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I went through a lot of these questions here on stackoverflow but I couldn't find solution for me / or I wasn't able to implement one for me. I hope you can help me.

The problem is with the flick/blink when I try to switch between pages I am using Routes in my App.js and Link in my Navbar. Here is the code:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/Profile" element={<Profile />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
const ListItem = ({ isActive, onClick, icon, name }) => {
  const className = `list${isActive ? " active" : ""}`;

  return (
    <li onClick={onClick} className={className}>
      <Link to={`/${name}`}>
        <span className="icon">
          <ion-icon name={icon} />
        </span>
        <span className="text">
          {name} {isActive ? "" : ""}
        </span>
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
};

const Navbar = () => {
  const [activeElem, setActive] = useState("Home");

  const handleToggle = (newValue) => {
    setActive(newValue);
  };

  console.log("active>>", activeElem);

  return (
    <div className="navigation">
      <ul>
        <ListItem
          key="Home"
          isActive={activeElem === "Home"}
          onClick={() => handleToggle("Home")}
          icon="home-outline"
          name="Home"
        />
        <ListItem
          key="Profile"
          isActive={activeElem === "Profile"}
          onClick={() => handleToggle("Profile")}
          icon="person-outline"
          name="Profile"
        />
        <ListItem
          key="Messages"
          isActive={activeElem === "Messages"}
          onClick={() => handleToggle("Messages")}
          icon="chatbubble-outline"
          name="Messages"
        />
        <ListItem
          key="Photos"
          isActive={activeElem === "Photos"}
          onClick={() => handleToggle("Photos")}
          icon="camera-outline"
          name="Photos"
        />
        <ListItem
          key="Settings"
          isActive={activeElem === "Settings"}
          onClick={() => handleToggle("Settings")}
          icon="settings-outline"
          name="Settings"
        />
        <div className="indicator"></div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Do you have a react/code playground to demo the issue or a screenshot/video/gif?

Comment: I made this short video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt9XCzSVPsI

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create the video. Do you happen to have a demo of your app/github repo/code playground? I'm wondering if this is purely a react-router issue or if there might in fact be something up in your Home component. There doesn't seem to be a flicker when you go back to the Profile tab, which leads me to believe something else might be the issue here that's making it so that your page basically refreshes (hence the white flicker).

Comment: It would basically be good to see the code of your Home / Profile components.

Comment: https://github.com/dziekiczan1/dive

Comment: I just realized that problem is with MotionWrap

Comment: Ah lol was just typing out an answer to say the same. Glad you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

So following on from my comment, I think the real issue is with this wrapper right here:

https://github.com/dziekiczan1/dive/blob/master/src/wrapper/MotionWrap.js#L8

It looks like the opacity transition is being a little messy?

Usually whenever I've seen the flickering happen in react router, it's usually something unrelated to the router itself that's causing the refresh or poor transition behavior.

Comment: But still I cant figure out a way to make it work to be honest with you

Comment: If you get rid of the MotionWrap, does it work fine?

If so, and you still want transitions, you could try the react-router-transition package instead?

Comment: Without it, app seems to be working just fine. Even with MotionWrap but with different values it also works lol. I will give it a try with the package you mentioned

Comment: Interesting. I did notice that in your video the background image looks weirder when you go to Home, so maybe the MotionWrap's values are just not set appropriately and it causes a weird transition/reset of the image maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this package which helps you mitigate the blink
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-transition